# python loops and string manipulation

Tags: python, string, list, loops

The function is called def expand_fmla (original)

The input variable to this function, original, is a string with a specific format: the first two positions in original have the symbols `*` or `+`, hence there are 4 possibilities for the first two positions of original: `++, **, +*` and `*+`. The subsequent positions have digits, at least 3 of them (0 to 9), possibly including repetition.

This function should return a formula which has the same digits and in the same order as in the original formula, and in between the digits the two operation symbols are alternatingly included.

For example:

```
expand_fmla('++123') should return '1+2+3'

expand_fmla('+*1234') should return '1+2*3+4'

expand_fmla('*+123456') should return '1*2+3*4+5*6'
```

How can I do this, I do not understand???

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: whats your question? ... surely its not please do my homework for me?

Comment: Seriously, WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED. If you want to get spoon fed it would be better to pay someone to do development for you. Show that you have made an effort and you will get an answer. "please internet, solve my problems for me because I don't want to" is not going to get you far

Answer (score 2):

This oughtta do it:

```
def expand_fmla(original):
    answer = []
    ops = original[:2]
    nums = original[2:]
    for i,num in enumerate(nums):
        answer.extend([num, ops[i%2]])
    return ''.join(answer[:-1])

In [119]: expand_fmla('+*1234')
Out[119]: '1+2*3+4'

In [120]: expand_fmla('*+123456')
Out[120]: '1*2+3*4+5*6'

In [121]: expand_fmla('++123')
Out[121]: '1+2+3'
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

using some `itertools` recipes, specially `itertools.cycle()` will be useful here:

```
from itertools import *
def func(x):
    op=x[:2]                             # operators
    opn=x[2:]                            # operands
    cycl=cycle(op)                       # create a cycle iterator of operators

    slice_cycl=islice(cycl,len(opn)-1)   # the no. of times operators are needed
                                         # is 1 less than no. of operands, so
                                         # use islice() to slice the iterator

    # iterate over the two iterables opn and          
    # slice_cycl simultanesouly using
    # izip_longest , and as the length of slice_cycl 
    # is 1 less than len(opn), so we need to use a fillvalue=""
    # for the last pair of items

    lis=[(x,y) for x,y in izip_longest(opn,slice_cycl,fillvalue="")]   


    return "".join(chain(*lis))

print func("++123")
print func("+*123")
print func("+*123456")
print func("*+123456")
```

**output:**

```
1+2+3
1+2*3
1+2*3+4*5+6
1*2+3*4+5*6
```

Comment: I always love seeing itertools examples. But I feel it would be a lot better to break up the generators into lines so it isn't so hard to read. Just an opinion.

Comment: @jdi you're right, it's hard to read these one-liner. So, I tried to break it into multiple lines to make it bit clearer.

Comment: Thats definitely an improvement. Though I was referring to splitting out the generators into variables. Do you think that it would be easier than seeing long one liners? Variable names tend to help with describing intent.